# onFling GestureDetector not working

Tags: java, android

Although my gesture detector works perfectly fine in another class of mine, when I use the fling to go to my new activity the gesture detector doesn't seem to be working for me. I cant find what wrong with it, any help?

```
public class FlingExample extends AppCompatActivity {

private int sequenceDelaySpeed;
private Bundle extras;
private TextView colourChangeSpeed;
private TextView speedWarning;
private static final int FLING_DISTANCE = 40;
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fling_example);

    colourChangeSpeed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.colourChangeText);
    speedWarning = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speedWarning);

    extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        sequenceDelaySpeed = extras.getInt("sequenceDelayTime");
    }
    colourChangeSpeed.setText(getString(R.string.colour_change_speed) + "\n" + sequenceDelaySpeed + " " + getString(R.string.milliseconds));


    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this,
            new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                                       float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                    if (e1.getY() - e2.getY() > FLING_DISTANCE) {//up
                        if(sequenceDelaySpeed > 50) {
                            sequenceDelaySpeed = sequenceDelaySpeed - 50;
                            colourChangeSpeed.setText(getString(R.string.colour_change_speed) + "\n" + sequenceDelaySpeed + getString(R.string.milliseconds));
                        }
                        else{
                            speedWarning.setText(getString(R.string.cannot_be_faster));
                        }
                        return true;

                    } else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > FLING_DISTANCE) {//down
                        if(sequenceDelaySpeed < 1500) {
                            sequenceDelaySpeed = sequenceDelaySpeed + 50;
                            colourChangeSpeed.setText(getString(R.string.colour_change_speed) + "\n" + sequenceDelaySpeed + " " + getString(R.string.milliseconds));
                        }
                        else{
                            speedWarning.setText(getString(R.string.cannot_be_slower));
                        }
                        return true;

                    } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > FLING_DISTANCE) {//right
                        return true;
                    }

                    return false; // works with true also
                }
            });

}

@Override // onTouchEvent required for onFling to be invoked...
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event); // ...pass to gestureDetector above
}
```

}

Comment: Where are you even starting your activity?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia its being started from the main activity when you fling to the left.

    if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > FLING_DISTANCE) {
                            Intent flingScreen = new Intent(StartScreen.this, FlingExample.class);
                            flingScreen.putExtra("sequenceDelayTime", sequenceDelayTime);
                            startActivityForResult(flingScreen, 2);
                            return true;

                        }

Comment: I dont see the intent

Comment: @RuchirBaronia 
Intent flingScreen = new Intent(StartScreen.this, FlingExample.class);
flingScreen.putExtra("sequenceDelayTime", sequenceDelayTime); 
startActivityForResult(flingScreen, 2); 
return true; }